# LM317 Voltage Regulator

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, linear-regulator, lm317

I want to regulate a voltage suppose 60 V, but I only have an LM317 (or any similar voltage regulator IC) with voltage regulation range of 30 V max.

Is there any way I can use a combination of two or more LM317s to make a voltage regulator that can regulate 60 V (or more)?

Can I feed the positive output of one LM317 as ground in the 2nd LM317, and measure the voltage between the output of the 2nd LM317 and ground of the 1st LM317?

I do not have any particular use or reason to ask this question. I am just curious if I can do that. This is just a hypothetical situation.

Comment: No, use something rated for 60 volt input.

Comment: Indeed no, I also think you need to educate yourself on how to do voltage regulation and what it means. For example: is that 60 V input or output voltage? What is the load current? Why 60 V? First get some experience with those LM317 below 30 V.

Comment: How much you want output voltage range? As each LM317 goes up to about 40V differential voltage, they could be arranged to drop down from 60V down.

Comment: Try NCP785 from ON Semiconductor.

Comment: I appreciate your situation of only having certain parts available, not a nice situation to be in and a predicament often unrecognised. But there's no neat 'multi-stack' solution. Please can you now edit and greatly improve your question, describing in detail the situation you have, your supply and your load. All in lots of detail. Without understanding the load and the power you'll dissipate in it, no-one can understand the power dissipated in the regulator. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract.

Comment: Now you've explained that you just wondered if you could do it and this question is hypothetical with hypothetical circumstances, you can now hypothetically afford some proper regulators. It's far too undetailed so vtc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variable power supply 200V](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/543825/variable-power-supply-200v)

Comment: Hm, I wrote a rather lengthy answer to your 200 V variable power supply question. All the same things still apply to 60 V; is it possible that either your accuracy requirements back then were totally out of proportion, or you're really just looking for an easy solution to a hard problem?

Comment: @MarcusMüller +1 Yes, and the best thing was that it focused on the how to do it properly. The following one (https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/554291/diy-power-supply) also received good feedback. Maybe the specs change further (200, 100, 60...) to something safer.

Comment: @MarcusMüller looks like this form focus more on someone's past. I dont know how is this question related to that question. Unfortunately people like you likes to work like dictator. MAybe you should make this a closed forum where one can post question only after approval from the supreme master

Comment: I've just declined two flags on this discussion. The moderator options are inadequate and "decline" is the best choice of those available.  People's concerns, often in opposition, are understood and sometimes there is no perfect solution. The wisdom of Solomon in dealing with people would help but is not always available.

Answer (score 3):

**Any** way? Yes there is. But if you require high currents they will get very hot:

[image: LM317 Tracking Preregulator Circuit]

<sub>Image source: Figure 15: Tracking Preregulator Circuit from [Texas Instruments LM317 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm317.pdf)</sub>

This is suggested by the TI datasheet. You can also use a BJT or MOSFET with a Zener to replace the first one by a simpler tracking regulator.

Comment: The tracking regulator will blow if the output is adjusted to a low value with a 60 V input.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could, but suboptimal. Have you thought about searching distributor stock on specs? Do this 1st next time and define ALL your specs 1st! DIRTFT(Do It Right The First Time).!

Can you use a TL783 with a heatsink?  We aren’t supposed to do shopping for you.

Comment: I mentioned clearly i want to use lm317 only!!

Answer (score 1):

The LM317 is, in normal operation, only limited to 30V across its terminals,
and that does not, technically, mean that it cannot regulate a 60V output, given
70V input; after all, there's no grounded pin on the IC.  That's only
ten volts applied to the LM317.

This is not recommended, however, because the LM317 is not completely
protected in such a situation against an output short, or other
transient situations that may occur on startup.